# Error in setting custom view to ArrayAdapter<String> for spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Below is my ArrayAdapter that I want to inflate view to fit my need of dropdown spinner.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrShirtType = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,shirtType)
        {
            private LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
                {
                    View vi = convertView;
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_view_style, parent);
                    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinner_textview);
                    ((TextView) vi).setTypeface(font1);
                    ((TextView) vi).setTextSize(65);
                    return vi;
                }
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
                {   
                    View vi = convertView;
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_view_style, parent);
                    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinner_textview);
                    ((TextView) vi).setTypeface(font1);
                    ((TextView) vi).setTextSize(65);
                    return vi;
                }
        };
```

**Question Updated**

Does the way that I inflate view to ArrayAdapter is correct ?
Below is the Error log

```
11-06 21:03:47.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 21:03:47.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
11-06 21:03:47.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:477)
11-06 21:03:47.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:497)
11-06 21:03:47.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-06 21:03:47.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-06 21:03:47.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at com.job.mommy.Shirt$1.getView(Shirt.java:90)
11-06 21:03:47.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):
```

Comment: inflater is null. you actually need an inflater to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You must initialize your inflater. For instance:

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```